# Centering text on top of multiple Divs?

Tags: css, html

I have a percentage bar and I'm trying to put some text over the front of it.

My example does that, but it centers over the smaller bar, not the full thing.

**My Question:** How can I get the word "test" centered over the full bar, not just the inner-smaller one.

**HTML**

```
<div id="bar1">
<div style="width:55%; text-align:center;">test</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#bar1 {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 13px; /* (height of inner div) / 2 + padding */
  padding: 3px;
  } 

#bar1 div 
{
    background-color: green;
    height: 20px;   
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-background-size:50px 50px;
    background-image:
        -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(center, circle, green, #00BB00 40%, green 80%);
        -webkit-animation:upbar 3s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes upbar
{
    0%{background-position:0 0}
    100%{background-position:0px -100px}
}
```

(apologies for the cheesiness of the bar. I'm trying to find a decent upward animation for it, so any suggestions welcome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better way but this works: http://jsfiddle.net/SFHft/

Use a second `div` with `position:absolute`:

```
<div id="bar1">
    <div class="anim" style="width:55%;"></div>
    <div class="text">TEST</div>
</div>

#bar1 div.anim 
{
    background-color: green;
    height: 20px;   
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-background-size:50px 50px;
    background-image:
        -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(center, circle, green, #00BB00 40%, green 80%);
        -webkit-animation:upbar 3s linear infinite;
}

#bar1 div.text 
{
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    color:#fff;
    top: 3px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Comment: I've gone with this one as it seems to work best for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

that's because your inner bar has `width:55%` of the parent div(`div.bar1`).
either give it a  full width, to bring the text to the center, or place your text outside.

you can also play with `position:absolute`

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/yAzvJ/)

Comment: using `position:absolute` requires a `position:relative` on the containing `div`, otherwise it's absolute to `body`

Answer (score 1):

You can center horizontally the child `div` with **`margin: 0 auto`**:

- [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nps5F/)
- [MDN about margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin)

Comment: This centers the actual percentage bar which makes it hard to see. Thanks for the help though, I got it sorted with the answers on here.